# Does Java 8’s ZoneOffset account for DST?

Tags: java, date, dst, java-time, timezone-offset

As I mentioned in title, does Java 8's ZoneOffset account for DST? Can I have different zone offsets in different summer/winter time?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a `ZoneOffset` is constant. To account for summer time (daylight saving time), you need a `ZoneId`, it accounts for DST and other changes in UTC offset. And will thus correspond to different `ZoneOffset`s in summer and winter *if* your time zone uses DST (far from all time zones do).

EDIT: `ZoneOffset` is a subclass of `ZoneId`, so you may say that a `ZoneOffset` is also a kind of `ZoneId`. But a special kind of `ZoneId` where the offset never changes. This inheritance relationship does not reflect the relationship between offsets and zones in real life, but has been made so because it is very often practical in programming.